# Accessing findViewById from Service

Tags: android, service

I want to Access `findViewById()` from an Service without passing it as an parameter or intent in the constructor of the service, Is that possible?

Her my code:

```
public class ManageDataService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    public void onCreate() {
        TextView longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.overview_position_longitude);
    }
}
```

I have to get the Activity's context somehow, right?

I didn't find any matching solutions on the internet.

Comment: You don't want to do that. Service updates your data model. Activity reads model and updates its Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really bad idea to update UI form service. 
I think good approach to to it is usage of BroadcastReceivers data Observer.
Just register one for your activity and pass value to update UI.